# Reducing Django queries! Get all results in one query rather than multiple?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my program, I am getting all items that belong to a table and are part of a certain category. This should be a really simple SQL query...but it seems like Django is making things much more complicated.

```
sqs = super(ItemView, self).get_queryset()
res = sqs.exclude(item_status='hidden')
return res
```

There are ~50 items that should be found. In the view, Django gets a queryset that is full of `<SearchResult>` objects. This gets sent to the front end where it is looped over and added to the page.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% individual_item %}
{% endfor %}
```

The Django toolbar is showing an individual query for every single item, so in this case, over 50 queries for what should be one.

Am I just misunderstanding how Django works and this is normal behavior? Or is there a way for me to run this as the one simple query it should be and send all the results from the view to the front end?

Comment: That is probably because you print data about related objects as well. Then you need `.select_related`, or `.prefetch_related`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that might be. However, since the program is using Haystack, I'm apparently using SearchQuerySets which won't work with `prefetch_related`. I'm trying to use sqs's `filter_and` but am running into wonderful errors now....